# Difference-in-differences length for pre and post period

Tags: causality, difference-in-difference

For difference-in-differences, do we need to select same duration/length for Pre period compared to Post period? For example, if post period is 5 months, do we need to select pre period to be of 5 months as well or can we use 12 months for pre period?

I saw it is common to use 12 months of data before intervention to control for the characteristics of test and control. However, I am not sure if we have to follow that 12 months or we have to follow same duration/length for pre period as in post period?

Comment: What are you looking at? The same period makes a lot of sense for, say, automobile accidents or other things that happen more the longer you observe. The length of the period matters less, if we talk about something that can be measured for a specific moment (e.g. a stock price). However, there might be good reasons to use comparable time intervals somehow matched time-points (e.g. seasonal variation could be averaged out to an extent by averaging over a whole year).

Comment: For example, an ad is shown in month 1, 2, 3 and we are trying to evaluate if the ad has any effect on sales by comparing the stores with ad vs stores w/o ad. Since ad was played for 3 months, do we need to use 3 months for pre period (before the time ad was shown) or could we use 12 months? We plan to divide the number of sales by number of months: sales in pre period/number of months, and sales in post period/3 as 3 months ad was shown.

Comment: I don't think you have to consider the same time-window pre and post treatment. You shuold rather be convincing that the time period you consider is sufficiently/appropriately long to assess the validity of the parellel trend assumption and to observe the effect of interest (e.g. due to the nature of the investigated phenomenon, the lack of other shocks). If other studies/scholars consider 12 months to investigate similar phenomena, is this motivated or is this the result of data contraints?

Answer (score 1):

We're discussing a similar question in my work team comparing healthcare intervention with variable post-period durations.

If you're normalizing the outcomes in the pre- and post-periods as a **monthly rate** (vs. simply summing the $y$ values in each period regardless of time length) then yes, a pre-post comparison may be conducted if you're reasonably certain the parallel trends assumption is valid.

However, a few points to consider:

- Are seasonal effects important in your study? If they are, best to use 12 month pre- and post-periods (or a multiple of 12) for all subjects.
- Computing outcome rates based on variable time periods per subject reduces the precision of your difference-in-differences estimate (5 months representing fewer observations than 12 months, increasing variability of measurements).